# Dataframe with incorrect index

Tags: python, dataframe

When I turn below file that is present in Python into a `pd.DataFrame`, it puts it as a first column without column name. I would like this as a second column with a header, but it does not work when using for example

```
table = ['         Mary Poppins             Went to school',
 '          In the morning           of April             2010',
 '          When            it               Suddenly,    rained        10'
 ]

.set_index(table) 
or 
pd.DataFrame(table, columns = ['text']).
```

pd.DataFrame:

```
                                     text
Mary Poppins Went to school          ...
In the morning of April 2010         ...
When it Suddenly, rained 10          ...
```

How to tackle this problem easily so that the text is in the text column?

Comment: How are you loading the data, `read_table` ?

Comment: As `pd.DataFrame(table)`

Comment: having the list you posted in table works for me

Comment: Can you please update your question with the exact code you're using. I can't seem to reproduce your issue. Putting your list with text (`table`) into `pd.DataFrame(table, columns = ['text'])` seems to work fine for me.